# How to send model values in controller in Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, yii2-model, yii2-grid

I have a view in which I have used `GridView` and `DetailView`. In my controller I am sending a model via it's ID. So in this way my `GridView` is working.

**Controller 1**

```
public function actionViewcreated($id)
{
         $model=$this->findModel($id);//the id of created form
    /*print_r($model);
    exit();*/
    $id = $model->id;
    $created_by = $model->created_by;
    $issuer = $model->issuer;
    $store = $model->store_id;
    $admin = $model->admin_incharge;
    $pm = $model->project_manager;

   .....
    // my other code

    return $this->render('viewcreated', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        'id'=> $model->id
        /*'searchModel' => $searchModel*/
    ]);


}
```

**View**

```
$this->title = $model->id;
$this->title = 'Outward Gate Pass';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
.
.
.
.
 <?= DetailView::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attributes' => [
                //'id',
                [
                        'label'=>'OGP Serial #',
                         'value' => function($d)
                         {
                             return $d->id;
                         }
                ],
                [
                    'label' => 'Created By',
                    'value' => function ($d) {
                        if(is_object($d))
                            return $d->created->name;
                    },
                    /* 'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'created_by', \app\models\User::toArrayList(), ['prompt' => "Users", 'class' => 'form-control']),*/

                ],
                'created_at',
                [
                    'label' => 'Store',
                    'value' => function ($d) {
                        if(is_object($d))
                            return $d->store->name;
                        return ' - ';
                    },
                    //'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel,'store_id',\app\models\Stores::toArrayList(),['prompt' => "Stores", 'class'=>'form-control']),
                ],
                'status',
                [
                    'label' => 'Issued To',
                    'value' => function ($d) {
                        if(is_object($d->user))
                            return $d->user->username;
                        return ' - ';
                    },
                    //'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'issuer', \app\models\User::toArrayList(), ['prompt' => "Users", 'class' => 'form-control']),

                ],
                'admin_incharge',
                'project_manager',
            ],
        ]) ?>
        <br>
      <?= GridView::widget([
         'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
          /*'filterModel' => $searchModel,*/
       'columns' => [

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
        'Meter Serial Number',
        'Issued To',
        'Store',         

 ],
]); ?>
        <form>
            <p>
                <a href="<?= URL::toRoute('ogpheader/viewsetpdf')?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="issue_pdf">Set PDF</a>
                <br/>

            </p>
        </form>
```

The resulted view:

[image: The resulted view is]

Now want to send my both `GridView` and `DetailView` into a new controller. For

**New Controller**

```
 public function actionViewsetpdf($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    print_r($model);
    exit();

}
```

Here I just want to see the values in my model. But when I click on the `Set PDF` button I always get

> Bad Request (#400)
>   Missing required parameters: id

I am stuck to it as I don't know why it's not showing me the data.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad request error means that you are not passing a GET parameter with the name `id`

your request string generation should look something like

`<?= URL::toRoute(['ogpheader/viewsetpdf','id'=>$model->id])?>`

Comment: i misplaced the array start identifier, and edited the answer, try this version

Comment: ok now it's showing me the values of upper part i.e. from `OGP Serial #` to `Project Manager` but not the values below them :(

Comment: You should send the your wanted id and/or load the correct model using your wanted class